# Django - Static pictures not found

Tags: python, django, static-files, django-staticfiles

Helo all,

I am running a Django application in development mode. I have collected static files into a /static/images/ directory in my project.

In my template I try to link an example image:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}items/no_image.jpeg"/>
    {{ STATIC_URL }}items/no_image.jpeg
```

(The bottom line is printing for debug purposes)

The picture shows with a broken link, and the bottom line prints out the correct directory:

```
 /static/items/no_image.jpeg
```

Inside my project, I do have the /static/items/no_image.jpeg file.

In my settings.py I have:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.dirname(__file__)+'/static/'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Can anybody help?

Thank you !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out the problem. The problem was I was using the wrong directory. STATIC_URL was named /site_media/ when it should be /static/. Changed it and everything now works clear as water...

Answer (score 2):

I think it's slash issue. Try

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static')
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be that. Tried making that change, but I still get the same error.

Comment: @VascoPatricio Wait, if you've collected your files to `/static/images/` where is `images` in your URL?

Comment: Well, I assume it is in /static/images/, correct? I collected the media and the folder /static/images/ was created in my project.

Comment: @VascoPatricio So you need to referet to it like `{{ STATIC_URL }}images/items/no_image.jpeg`

Comment: Sorry, I got it wrong there. It's /static/items/, not /static/images/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've misunderstood the collecting of static files. There's no need to collect them into a target directory with the `collectstatic` command during development. That's meant to be done for *deployment*.

During dev, you only add the django.contrib.staticfiles app, then specify the STATIC_ROOT, STATIC_URL and STATICFILES_DIRS as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#basic-usage).

Then, in your base urlconf you need to add the url rules for the staticfiles as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development). That's it for "development mode".

In production mode, you run the `collectstatic` command first, then shove the resulting directory over to the server where your apache (or nginx or whatever) is running, and let him serve that directory unter www.yoururl.com/static/

The whole story about handling staticfiles in django almost drove me nuts ... and even today I have to think for some minutes when trying to remember it or explain it. :-/ Don't worry if it confuses you sometimes.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. However, the problem here is the picture is not accessible when I access the URL, and it should be (serving static files works while rendering templates in development).

Answer (score 0):

I think I recently had a similar issue. Try placing your images directly in /static/ instead of /static/items/. If you want to be able to directly link to /static/items/sample.jpg you need to add /static/items/ to your STATIC_ROOT in SETTINGS